Request to have MathJax enabled please?
Ok, so according to the response to my meta question from the overwhelming feeling of everyone on crypto is that we would benefit massively from having Mathjax enabled.
So, as discussed on chat with one of our lovely community people, Dori, I am now making this a proper request.
To summarise the points made there:

Votes on posts saying yes received around 30 upvotes in total (35, including downvotes on non-agreeing posts) vs 2 (including downvotes on yes posts).
The alternatives from an end user perspective (image rendering via taking screenshots of Math.SE, the use of <sup> tags etc) are much more cumbersome than TeX notation.
Its presence suggests more mathematical rigour and may appeal more to researchers.
TeX is a de facto standard for scientific publishing. This wasn't explicitly said, but the nature of most papers over the last 20 years was highlighted.
The point was made that many people may would use (and abuse) MathJax, although that is not necessarily bad (see rigour).
Concerns over bandwidth and the "only if you need it" general rule were also highlighted.

A sample of questions highlighted that would greatly benefit from the presence of MathJax:

How to provide secure "vanity" bitcoin address service?
Taking advantage of one-time pad key reuse?
What is the relation between RSA & Fermat's little theorem?
Is calculating a hash code for a large file in parallel less secure than doing it sequentially?
How robust is discrete logarithm in $GF(2^n)$?

So, this is our request to have MathJax enabled please. To everyone on crypto, this is our request, so if you feel that I've missed out a valuable question that further strengthens our case, by all means edit it in. Likewise, if you feel you can make any of the summary points better, likewise feel free to chip in.

MathJax is now enabled for the main site.
